# "gcloud container clusters create fails" with "container.clusters.create" permission error

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When I create kubernetes cluster with gcloud container clusters create command, a permission error occurs as follows:

```
$ gcloud container clusters create my-k8s
WARNING: Currently node auto repairs are disabled by default. In the future this will change and they will be enabled by default. Use `--[no-]enable-autorepair` flag  to suppress this warning.
WARNING: Starting in Kubernetes v1.10, new clusters will no longer get compute-rw and storage-ro scopes added to what is specified in --scopes (though the latter will remain included in the default --scopes). To use these scopes, add them explicitly to --scopes. To use the new behavior, set container/new_scopes_behavior property (gcloud config set container/new_scopes_behavior true).
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.create" permission for "projects/test-project".
```

How I can solve this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I could start with the following command:

```
gcloud container clusters create my-k8s --project  test-project-xxxxxx
```

Note: Without a project name without number, the creation fails with the same error.

```
gcloud container clusters create my-k8s --project  test-project
```